# Position in Python Lists

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code for operation between each element with all the other elements of a list but not with itself. Below is the code.

```
list = [10,20,30,30,40,50,50,50,60,70];
for i in list:
        sum=i;
        for j in list:
                if list.index(i) != list.index(j):
                       s=(50-((j-i)/2))*0.13;
                       sum+=s;  
        print("score of %d is %f"%(i,sum));
```

But still the code is not working. It is not satisfying the `if` condition of positions.

Comment: please  add expected output as question is not making any sense to me...

Comment: 30 is repeated. So, In case of repetition, all the duplicates will be excluded. Is that expected?

Comment: Duplicates should not be excluded....i & j should not belong to same position....eg:30 in position 3 should operate with 30 in position 4 but not with 30 in position 3

Comment: The output should be....score of 10 is 48.67, score of 20 is 45.23, score of 30 is 51.78, score of 30 is 51.78......so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` to get the index. This may do what you up to:

```
lis = [10, 20, 30, 30, 40, 50, 50, 50, 60, 70]

for idx1, el1 in enumerate(lis):
    sum_ = el1
    for  idx2, el2 in enumerate(lis):
        if idx1 != idx2:
             sum_ += (50 - (el2 - el1)/2) * 0.13
        print("score of %d is %f"%(idx1, sum_))
```

Comment: I think the `print()` is indented too far. It should line up with the `for idx2, el2 ...`

Comment: The `print()` is just for debugging and shows what is going on. For example, you can see that the sum does not change if both indices are equal, i.e. once per each inner loop.